# How to debug a Spring Boot application via SpringBootTest

Tags: spring-boot, testing, spring-test

I'm new to Spring Boot and I really like it especially when it comes to eliminate the boilerplate code.
I have created a test class to test my `NBRController`:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = NewBusinessRevitalizationApplication.class, 
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"management.port=0"})
public class NBRControllerTest extends TestCase {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Value("${local.management.port}")
    private int mgt;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @Test
    public void getApplicationByAgencyIdAndStatusTest() {
        String uri = "http://localhost:" + this.port + "/nbr-services/applications/{status}?agencyIds=123456,56765,678576";
        Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
        vars.put("status", "SAVED");
        ResponseEntity<String> response = testRestTemplate.getForEntity(uri, String.class, vars);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

If I run it in debug mode I can only debug the Test class and not my `NBRController` class:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/nbr-services")
public class NBRController {

    @Autowired
    private NBRServices nbrServices;

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NBRController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/configuration/environment/{environment}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getConfiguration(@PathVariable("environment") String environment) throws RemoteException {
        logger.debug("environment={}", environment);
        String result = nbrServices.getConfiguration(environment);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I have tried to setup the Tomcat debug port but not luck.
The only way I can debug my `NBRController` is run it in debug mode and call my RestAPI from the browser, but I want to use my unit test. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58364490/difference-between-webenvironment-random-port-and-webenvironment-mock, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39865596

Comment: Get response from the actual uri is kinda redundant. Spring Boot test has the `MockMvc` for testing the rest api. Follow this tutorial for more details: https://www.springboottutorial.com/unit-testing-for-spring-boot-rest-services

Comment: Is it your actual code? The endpoint you are trying to connect to in your test does not exist in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

I had this happening when I accidentally had 2 controller methods with the same path mapping.

Other alternatives for debugging:

### Only mock the server using mockMVC

It is possible to debug a system by not using a split webEnvironment, but to use spring MockMVC to make direct method calls to controllers instead of http calls.

```
@SpringBootTest(
   webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK // this is the default
)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class MyTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test public void myTest() {
     mockMvc.perform("/mypath");
     // ...
  }
}
```

This will not actually make http calls between the jUnit class and the controller, so this http processing part would not be tested.

### Start the server separately and attach a remote debugger

1. In the IDE, start the application can in debugging mode
2. When application it is up and running, start JUnit tests which contain any http client, e.g. RestAssured.

This will spawn 2 JVMs, but the IDE is connected to both, so all breakpoints work.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Intellij 2020.3 and I could able to debug my controller.

1. Stop all the running instances from intellij.
2. Simply put debug pointers in right controller method and run your test case in debug mode.
3. Unless you are hitting wrong endpoint, it should work.
4. Also you can try to evaluate your testRestTemplate call in test case in debug mode, in case it is failing in network itself.

Answer (score 0):

You're possibly running on a different port to the one you think you are.

The SpringBootTest annotation is what controls the test port e.g.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
```

Comment: Can you explain how to debug the RestController then? I have changed to  SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT has you suggested but still skip the braking points.

Comment: In your setup debug should work just fine. One thing to check is that your rest call is going to the server that you think it is. Do you have any other instances running that aren't in debug mode ?

force the port to be something different from the norm, e.g. server.port=9123 in application.properties/yaml, then do a netstat to check it's up and running when you start your test.

Also try putting a breakpoint on a line in a postConstruct method, just to prove to yourself that you're hitting the app that you are starting in the test.

Comment: I'm hitting the right services because is @SpringBootTest that start a service to call, the problem is that from Intellij if I run the Unit test in Debug mode it runs the Test in debug but not the Service

Comment: Did you find an answer to this problem?

Comment: As far as i can understand, What you need is a remote debugging ability on your Embedded Spring Application. I have a similar requirement. Looks like the `SpringBootTest` is running it internally. If only I had some way to specify the debugging port, i would be able to do it. As of now, I have to run my application separately.

Answer (score 0):

In the Uri you are appending http://local host +port , which is not necessary , testRestTemplate does it for you. Remove that and try you may hit the debug point

Comment: If this doesn't work let me know, I am answering via mobile. Will send from pc tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Here is example to write Junit for Rest layer for Spring boot 2 + JUnit 5

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class RestTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private Rest  rest;
    
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void init() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(rest).build();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void getTest() throws Exception {
        String url = "/test";
        ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get(url));
        resultActions.andExpect(status().isOk());

    }
    
}

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public class Rest  {
    
        
        
        @GetMapping
        public @ResponseBody String get()  {
            
            return "success";
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, i use `maven-spring-boot` plugin and when i debug, its from a Maven run config.   Maybe that is what is wrong with what you are doing?    The `maven-spring-boot` plugin, during test phase, will start spring boot server before the test runs.

If you want to do it with a command line app , then you have to manually load the Spring context and execute the main class from a couple lines of code, before your test runs.  I don't remember off-hand how to do it.