Get server port when running Spring Boot integration tests in a mock environment
My Spring Boot integration test classes look like this:
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT, classes = RestSpringBeans.class)
public interface ApiTestConfiguration {
    // tests omitted
}

In RestSpringBeans I define some beans that are used by the tests, including this one:
@Lazy
@TestConfiguration
@Import(BootstrapData.class)
public class RestSpringBeans {

    @Bean
    RestClient restClient(@LocalServerPort int port, @Autowired RestClient.Builder restClientBuilder) {
        return restClientBuilder.baseUrl("http://localhost:" + port).build();
    }
}

I want to switch to using a mock environment, which can be achieved by deleting the webEnvironment attribute from @SpringBootTest (because a mock environment is the default).
After I make this change I get the following error when creating the RestClient bean

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'local.server.port' in value "${local.server.port}"

Unsuccessful Attempt 1
I tried setting the config property server.port = 9999 and injecting @Value("${server.port}") instead of @LocalServerPort, but it didn't work.
Unsuccessful Attempt 2
The following works with webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT, but when webEnvironment = MOCK the property local.server.port is null
@Bean
RestClient restClient(@Autowired Environment environment, @Autowired RestClient.Builder restClientBuilder) {
    var port = environment.getProperty("local.server.port", Integer.class);
    return restClientBuilder.baseUrl("http://localhost:" + port).build();
}

Minimal Demo
Download this demo application, then switch to the run-tests-in-mock-env branch. The problem can be demonstrated by following these steps

Run RandomPortTests to see the test pass when a mock environment is not used
Run MockRestClientTests to see the test fail when a mock environment is used with RestClient. The server port is defined in application.properties
Run MockWebClientTests to see the test pass when a mock environment is used with WebTestClient

If you start the server before running (2), the tests do pass. However, it's not necessary to start the server before running (3). If it's possible for the test in (3) to pass without starting the server, then it ought to be possible with (2), because the only difference between them is the web client library.

As indicated in the Spring Boot reference guide, when describing Testing with a Mock Environment:

By default, @SpringBootTest does not start the server but instead
sets up a mock environment for testing web endpoints.

The same guide indicates as well (emphasis mine):

By default, @SpringBootTest will not start a server. You can use
the webEnvironment attribute of @SpringBootTest to further
refine how your tests run:

MOCK(Default): Loads a web ApplicationContext and provides a
mock web environment. Embedded servers are not started when using
this annotation. If a web environment is not available on your
classpath, this mode transparently falls back to creating a regular
non-web ApplicationContext. It can be used in conjunction with
@AutoConfigureMockMvc or @AutoConfigureWebTestClient for
mock-based testing of your web application.
RANDOM_PORT: Loads a WebServerApplicationContext and provides
a real web environment. Embedded servers are started and listen on
a random port.
DEFINED_PORT: Loads a WebServerApplicationContext and
provides a real web environment. Embedded servers are started and
listen on a defined port (from your application.properties) or on
the default port of 8080.


It means that when the mock environment is configured there is no server port, because there isn't an actual server running.
In consequence, you need to decide whether you want to test a mock environment or the full server created by the random or desired web environments by @SpringBootTest.
If you want to use the mock environment, as advised in the same guide, you can use @AutoConfigureMockMvc and @MockMvc and define your tests in a way similar to the following:
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class ApiTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    // Perform the necessary tests using mockMvc
    @Test
    void shouldXXX() throws Exception {      
      this.mockMvc.perform(get("/one-of-the-paths-defined-in-your-app"))
         .andDo(print())
         .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}

Note that as indicated in the same guide, and as in the example 3 that you provided as well, you can use WebTestClient for testing the mock environment too: SpringBootTest provides a WebTestClient configured accordingly to the web environment you chose that you can use in your tests out of the box.
Testing with a mock environment has some limitations; as stated in the Spring Boot guide:

Testing within a mocked environment is usually faster than running
with a full servlet container. However, since mocking occurs at the
Spring MVC layer, code that relies on lower-level servlet container
behavior cannot be directly tested with MockMvc.
For example, Spring Boot’s error handling is based on the “error
page” support provided by the servlet container. This means that,
whilst you can test your MVC layer throws and handles exceptions as
expected, you cannot directly test that a specific custom error page
is rendered. If you need to test these lower-level concerns, you can
start a fully running server as described in the next section.

If you want to test the actual running server created by @SpringBootTest when you configure it with a desired or random port, then go on and configure RestClient or the tool you consider more appropriate to interact with the running server.
Note that in addition to the aforementioned WebTestClient - this time configured to interact with the full fledged server - in this case @SpringBootTest already registers a convenient TestRestTemplate for this purpose.
You can, of course, use RestTemplate as well, or any other HTTP client of your choice.
If required use different profiles, using the annotation @ActiveProfiles, for instance, to perform one of other type of tests.

If it's possible to use a TestRestTemplate or a WebClientTest in the mock environment, then it should also be possible to use a RestClient given that all 3 are HTTP client libraries. But I can't figure out how to set the base URL/port when using RestClient.

Sorry for the late reply @Dónal, and thank you for the feedback. When I mentioned TestRestTemplate and WebTestClient, sorry for the typo, I did it in the context of using a random port, not the mock environment. On one hand, TestRestTemplate will only be autowired if using a random port. On the other, when you configure a mock environment by not defining a port and using @AutoConfigureMockMvc as in your MockWebClientTests example, under the hood, Spring will configure a WebTestClient that binds to mock infrastructure as well, not to an actual server: please, consider debugging...

the connect method in org.springframework.test.web.servlet.client.MockMvcHttpConnector and check that this and not a true HTTP connector is the one executed.

1st Scenario: Run MockRestClientTests to see the test pass when a mock environment is used with RestClient. The server port is defined in application.properties
Possible Solution:
I tried hacky way to solve.
Change server.port to local.server.port in application.properties.
Use @Value("${local.server.port}") int port in restClient bean.
Modify MockRestClientTests to this:
@SpringBootTest(classes = MockRestClient.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class MockRestClientTests {

    @Autowired
    private RestClient restClient;

    @Test
    void getUsers() {
        var status = restClient.get().uri("/users")
            .retrieve()
            .toBodilessEntity()
            .getStatusCode();

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, status);
    }
}

@Lazy
@TestConfiguration
class MockRestClient {

    @Bean
    RestClient restClient(@Value("${local.server.port}") int port, @Autowired RestClient.Builder restClientBuilder) {
        return restClientBuilder.baseUrl("http://localhost:" + port)
            // We need to change the default request factory in order to use PATCH requests
            // https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31590
            .requestFactory(new JdkClientHttpRequestFactory())
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .build();
    }
}


2nd Scenario: Run RandomPortTests to see the test pass when a mock environment is used.
Possible Solution:
Create a sample test-properties in the test/resources.
local.server.port=9999

Update RandomPortTests to this:
@SpringBootTest(classes = RandomPortRestClient.class)
class RandomPortTests {

    @Autowired
    private RestClient restClient;

    @Test
    void getUsers() {
        var status = restClient.get().uri("/users")
            .retrieve()
            .toBodilessEntity()
            .getStatusCode();

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, status);
    }
}

@Lazy
@TestConfiguration
@PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
class RandomPortRestClient {

    @Bean
    RestClient restClient(@LocalServerPort int port, @Autowired RestClient.Builder restClientBuilder) {
        return restClientBuilder.baseUrl("http://localhost:" + port)
            // We need to change the default request factory in order to use PATCH requests
            // https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31590
            .requestFactory(new JdkClientHttpRequestFactory())
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .build();
    }
}

It will work.

@Dónal See if this works.

The problem with this approach is that the server has to be started separately in order for the test to pass which isn't very practical in a CI environment. There's no need to start the server separately if you use WebTestClient instead of RestClient. I've left a comment on a Spring issue explaining this
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31275#issuecomment-2346302316
Thanks for all your help

@Dónal I have updated my answer. Please check if that makes sense.

You say "Run RandomPortTests to see the test pass when a mock environment is not used", but RandomPortTests is using a mock environment

@Dónal Fixed. Actually, I added your scenario lines previously.

Spring acquire it by
String port = environment.getProperty("local.server.port", Integer.class);

where environment is an instance of org.springframework.core.env.Environment. You can @Autowired it in your bean.
EDIT
If you use SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK no web server started, so there is no port to connect. According to this you have to use something called @MockMVC whatever that means.

This works with webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT, but when webEnvironment = MOCK the property local.server.port is null

I think in MOCK configuration there is no tomcat started, so there is no open port.

Here is some more information on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58364490/difference-between-webenvironment-random-port-and-webenvironment-mock
