# Can @WebMvcTest have two controllers

Tags: java, web-testing

I am Trying to test two different controller classes , Since I want to test one method each from the both classes and I will be using @WebMvcTest , My question is there a way to inject mocks into both classes , 
something like this may be ?

```
@WebMvcTest(HomeController.class , BookController.class)
public class ControllerTest{
```

ofcourse this gives error , so does that mean when using @WebMvcTest we can test only methods in one controller ? per class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`@WebMvcTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html) accepts `Class<?>[]` as `value()` :

```
public @interface WebMvcTest {
  ...
    @AliasFor("controllers")
    Class<?>[] value() default {};
  ...
}
```

Passing a single value (possible only because it is annotation) or an array is so legal.
Your problem is you don't use the correct syntax to declare a literal array.
Try :

```
@WebMvcTest({HomeController.class, BookController.class})
public class ControllerTest{
```

Note that by annotating your test class with `@WebMvcTest` without valuing any param in the annotation declaration :

```
@WebMvcTest
public class ControllerTest{
```

all Spring controllers are added in the Spring context.

Comment: when we use  WebMvcTest  annotation we don't need to use  SpringbootTest annotation   @davidxxx  Is that right ?

Comment: Indeed. It is an alternative. SpringBootTest annotation loads all the context (it makes tests slower) while WebMvcTest annotation  loads only Mvc beans or what you specify as you did (it makes tests faster). You can read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39865596/difference-between-using-mockmvc-with-springboottest-and-using-webmvctest

Comment: this is because I need to add  properties = "classpath:application.properties to class

Comment: if I want to load context from app.properties

Comment: @TestPropertySource( "classpath:application.properties") may be I can add this ? because I need application.properties a bean is defined there

Comment: You can add it. But I think that it is probably not required. It should be considered by Spring without need to specify it.