# Cannot run Unit Tests against REST layer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, jhipster

I cannot unit test the web layer using jhipster ([according to spring gs guides](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/#_test_the_application)):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
public class FlightControllerTest {


    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private FlightService flightService;

    @Test
    public void testCreate() throws Exception {

        FlightDto expected = new FlightDto();
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(expected, "id", 1L);

        when(flightService.createFlight(any(FlightDto.class))).thenReturn(expected);

        FlightDto flightDto = new FlightDto();
        flightDto.setNumber("CAI-123400");

        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/api/flight")
                .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(flightDto)))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(header().string("Location", endsWith("/api/flight/1")));
    }

}
```

The above Unit test success in case of green-field [spring boot project](https://github.com/mhewedy-playground/jhipster-UnitTest-Web/tree/master/springboot-no-jhipster), but fails in case of [green-field spring boot-based jhipster project](https://github.com/mhewedy-playground/jhipster-UnitTest-Web/tree/master/springboot-with-jhipster):

When run Unit Test in jhispter project (springboot-with-jhipster) from FlightResource I got:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test

    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.getOrFindConfigurationClasses(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:202)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.processMergedContextConfiguration(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper.processMergedContextConfiguration(WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper.java:35)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:409)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildDefaultMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:323)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:277)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:105)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:152)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:143)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner.<init>(SpringRunner.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can run the test with this code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

//@WebMvcTest remove @WebMvcTest
//add SpringBootTest
@SpringBootTest(classes = JhUnittestRestApp.class)
public class FlightResourceTest {

    //@Autowired remove anotation
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private FlightService flightService;

    @Autowired
    private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter;

    @Autowired
    private PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableArgumentResolver;

    @Autowired
    private ExceptionTranslator exceptionTranslator;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        //initialize the bean
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        final FlightResource flightResource = new FlightResource(flightService);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(flightResource)
            .setCustomArgumentResolvers(pageableArgumentResolver)
            .setControllerAdvice(exceptionTranslator)
            .setConversionService(createFormattingConversionService())
            .setMessageConverters(jacksonMessageConverter).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreate() throws Exception {

        FlightDTO expected = new FlightDTO();
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(expected, "id", 1L);

        when(flightService.save(any(FlightDTO.class))).thenReturn(expected);

        FlightDTO flightDto = new FlightDTO();
        flightDto.setNumber("CAI-123400");
        //update the url to /api/flights so that the test can pass 
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/api/flights")
            .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(flightDto)))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isCreated())
            .andExpect(header().string("Location", endsWith("/api/flights/1")));
    }

}
```

Your FlightControllerTest is working in your [springboot-no-jhipster](https://github.com/mhewedy-playground/jhipster-UnitTest-Web/tree/master/springboot-no-jhipster) project because the main class of the [project is annotated with @SpringBoot](https://github.com/mhewedy-playground/jhipster-UnitTest-Web/blob/master/springboot-no-jhipster/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java) According to the [documentation of @SpringBoot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html)

```
The @SpringBootApplication annotation is equivalent to using:
@Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan with their default attributes
```

Since JHipster needs some more configuration than just the default, JHipster is not using @SpringBootApplication as you can [see in your project](https://github.com/mhewedy-playground/jhipster-UnitTest-Web/blob/master/springboot-with-jhipster/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/JhUnittestRestApp.java). This is perfectly OK and works without problems.

On the other hand the error message of your test is saying that it can't detect @SpringBootConfiguration. There are other annotation e.g. @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest that are rocomandet to use for the test. Actually there are some inconsistencies on which annotation in main config class fits with the test annotations see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39865596/difference-between-using-mockmvc-with-springboottest-and-using-webmvctest) or [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5987).

Comment: So it is to load the whole spring application (as in regular integration test), but mock the Controller dependencies, correct? And it is the only option?

Comment: Since "All Roads Lead to Rome" It can be that there are other ways of doing this. In order to run your test with annotation RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
and WebMvcTest you need to use annotation ContextConfiguration. The problem with ContextConfiguration is that is harder to config in a JHipster project since the configuration is spread over different modules. For me it works perfectly fine the IntegrationTest as provided by JHipster

Comment: You know, it takes tooo long to just run a UNIT test, which should run much faster!

Comment: At the moment I did not get the time to get more into deep to see how it can be configured to run just like you wish. I agree with you UNIT test should be fast. To get a solution for this it will be get more in deep to see what WebMvcTest-annotation is expecting for defaults beside SpringBootApplication-annotation.