# SpringBoot Controller test using Mockito & jUnit5 failing as Spring is unable to create bean of PropertyService class which loads properties?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I have a simple spring boot project--

Here is the project structure-

[image]

If I run my spring boot application, it runs fine without any errors. I was able to get all the customers, get a single customer, delete a customer and add a customer through my rest controller methods.

Through `Postman` I am able to add customers--

```
<Customer>
<firstName>TestData</firstName>
<lastName>Test</lastName>
<gender>M</gender>
<date>2020-01-26T09:00:00.000+0000</date>
<authId>6AE-BH3-24F-67FG-76G-345G-AGF6H</authId>
<addressdto>
<city>Test City</city>
<country>Test Country</country>
</addressdto>
</Customer>
```

**Response**

`Customer with 34 sucessfully added`

This means while the application is up, it is able to instantiate `PropertyService.java`.
thus I am able to access an authentication id which is present in my `application-dev.properties` through `PropertyService.java`. The same property is present in my **src/test/resources**-> `application.properties`.

There are two problems--

1. Now when I run my `HomeControllerTest.java` class as`jUnit test` , I
   am getting a error.  I debugged and found out the root cause of the
   error. Inside my `HomeController.java` class , it is unable to
   instantiate the `PropertyService.java` class, so i am getting a
   `null pointer exception` there.Thus the further execution of test class failed.
2. I am unable to access the authId through `PropertyService.java` in my test class., so I had to hardcode.

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this issue? And how do I fix it?

**HomeController.java**

```
@PostMapping("/customer")
    public ResponseEntity<String> addCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerDto customerDto) {
        String message = "";
        ResponseEntity<String> finalMessage = null;
        try {
            if ((!customerDto.getAuthId().equals(propertyService.getKeytoAddCustomer()))) {
                System.out.println("If check failed: "+propertyService.getKeytoAddCustomer());
                System.out.println("Unauthorized access attempted");
                message = "Unauthorized access attempted";
                finalMessage = new ResponseEntity<>(message, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
            System.out.println("If check passed :"+propertyService.getKeytoAddCustomer());

            Customer customer = mapper.mapToEntity(customerDto);
            customerService.addCustomer(customer);
            message = "Customer with " + customer.getId() + " sucessfully added";
            finalMessage = new ResponseEntity<>(message, HttpStatus.OK);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            message = "Failed to add customer due to " + e.getMessage();
            finalMessage = new ResponseEntity<>(message, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        return finalMessage;
    }
```

**PS- `equals(propertyService.getKeytoAddCustomer()))` (Problem 1) --> here I am getting the `null pointer exception`**

**PropertyService.java**

```
package com.spring.liquibase.demo.utility;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class PropertyService {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public String getKeytoAddCustomer() {
        return env.getProperty("auth.key.to.add.customer");
    }
}
```

**HomeControllerTest.java**

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class HomeControllerTest {
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @InjectMocks
    private HomeController homeController;

    @MockBean
    private CustomerService customerService;
//
//  @Autowired
//  private PropertyService propertyService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(homeController).build();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testaddCustomer() throws Exception {
        String uri = "/customer";
        CustomerDto custDto = this.mockCustomerObject();
        String actualResult = mvc
                .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(uri).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(asJsonString(custDto)))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk()).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
        Assertions.assertEquals(actualResult, "Customer with " + custDto.getId() + " sucessfully added");
    }

    private CustomerDto mockCustomerObject() {
        CustomerDto cusDto = new CustomerDto();
        AddressDto addressDto = new AddressDto();
        addressDto.setCity("BBSR");
        addressDto.setCountry("INDIA");
        cusDto.setDate(new Date());
        cusDto.setFirstName("Biprojeet");
        cusDto.setLastName("KAR");
        cusDto.setGender("M");
        cusDto.setAuthId(" 6AE-BH3-24F-67FG-76G-345G-AGF6H");
        cusDto.setAddressdto(addressDto);
        return cusDto;

    }

    public static String asJsonString(CustomerDto cusDto) {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(cusDto);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**PS- I have commented out the codes as I am unable to access the prop file here.Need help here as well(Problem 2)**

**application.properties-- inside src/test/resources**

```
# DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql******useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=****
spring.datasource.password=****

# Hibernate
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
logging.level.com=DEBUG

customer.auth.key = 6AE-BH3-24F-67FG-76G-345G-AGF6H
```

application-dev.properties

```
same as above
```

**application.properties inside->src/main/resources**

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
logging.level.com=DEBUG
server.port=8080
```

**jUnit Error Log**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<500>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:627)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:196)
    at com.spring.liquibase.demo.controller.HomeControllerTest.testaddCustomer(HomeControllerTest.java:50)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:436)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:170)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:166)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:113)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After gone through with your repo here is the final code

```
@WebMvcTest(HomeController.class)
class HomeControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mvc;

@MockBean
private CustomerService customerService;

@MockBean
private PropertyService propertyService;

@MockBean
private EntityToDtoMapper mapper;


@Test
public void testaddCustomer() throws Exception {
    String uri = "/customer";
    CustomerDto custDto = this.mockCustomerObject();
    Customer customer = getCustomerEntity();
    Mockito.when(mapper.mapToEntity(Mockito.any(CustomerDto.class))).thenReturn(customer);
    String actualResult = mvc
            .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(uri).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(asJsonString(custDto)))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk()).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
    Assertions.assertEquals(actualResult, "Customer with " + custDto.getId() + " sucessfully added");
}

private CustomerDto mockCustomerObject() {
    CustomerDto cusDto = new CustomerDto();
    AddressDto addressDto = new AddressDto();
    addressDto.setCity("BBSR");
    addressDto.setCountry("INDIA");
    cusDto.setDate(new Date());
    cusDto.setFirstName("Biprojeet");
    cusDto.setLastName("KAR");
    cusDto.setGender("M");
    cusDto.setAuthId(" 6AE-BH3-24F-67FG-76G-345G-AGF6H");
    cusDto.setAddressdto(addressDto);
    return cusDto;

}


private Customer getCustomerEntity() {
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    Address address = new Address();
    address.setCity("BBSR");
    address.setCountry("INDIA");
    customer.setDate(new Date());
    customer.setFirstName("Biprojeet");
    customer.setLastName("KAR");
    customer.setGender("M");
    customer.setAddress(address);
    return customer;

}

public static String asJsonString(CustomerDto cusDto) {
    try {
        return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(cusDto);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

The issue over here that you are mixing the concepts. In your implementation you were trying to do unit testing but was expecting the behaviour of integration.

As you been using Spring boot with it's test starter kit which comes with the dependencies of framework like JUnit and Mockito, You can easily mock those classes and methods which throwing the Null pointer exception by using mockitio framework because server is not running and IOC container is not up that's why those are NULL.

So in your code CustomerService, PropertyService and EntityToDtoMapper was NULL.

So question over here is how we can upload the spring application context without starting the server.

It can be done by two ways either load the whole spring application context by using @SpringBootTest and @AutoConfigureMockMvc annotations.

Or we can narrow the spring application context only for the controller itself by using @WebMvcTest annotation

So the solution which I used over here is narrow the test to the controller only by using  @WebMvcTest(HomeController.class) annotation.

But still those CustomerService, PropertyService and EntityToDtoMapper are NULL. So to mock those classes We can use either @Mock or @MockBean annotation, but there is a slight difference between those annotation

> The Mockito.mock() method allows us to create a mock object of a class or an interface and the @MockBean to add mock objects to the Spring application context. The mock will replace any existing bean of the same type in the application context.

So as we have uploaded the spring application context for the controller so the controller is expecting those beans in the application context as well, which can be achieved by @MockBean annotation.

After mocking all those beans your controller bean will be created but there are the methods where you expecting some return values so you have to code the expected return value in your code which could be done like that

```
Mockito.when(mapper.mapToEntity(Mockito.any(CustomerDto.class))).thenReturn(customer);
```

if you miss this particular step then in the controller you will get an NULL pointer exception on this line of code

```
message = "Customer with " + customer.getId() + " sucessfully added";
```

Because you code

```
Customer customer = mapper.mapToEntity(customerDto);
```

will return NULL.

I hope this will help and motivate you to get more knowledge on those concepts.

Please let me know if any further help is required

Comment: Yes that maybe the issue that my app is not up. But its not working, I am getting the same error. My application is up, and i added the `@Mock` annotation --didn t work. My app was not up+added `@Mock` annotation--disn t work.

Comment: Are you still getting the 500?

Comment: If yes, then it must be coming from the PropertyService class where you have Autowired Environment. 
So you have to mock Environment class as well.
But in real scenario this is kind of integration testing, not the unit testing because here you are accessing all the three layers i.e controllers, service, and persistence layer

Comment: `@Mock
 private PropertyService propertyService;`
 
 `@Mock
 private Environment env;`
Still did not work. :(

Comment: if i use `@SpringBootTest` above my test class then aslo same error, `PropertyService` is `null`. Please help me out. Try to recreate the issue in ur local if u have free time.

Comment: Could you please share your code or repo, So that I could verify the issue on my local

Comment: sure, here is the source code-- [https://github.com/Arpan619Banerjee/SpringBoot_rest_api ]

Comment: Sorry Arpan I couldn't manage to go through with the code completely because of busy schedule and its required a bit of DB setup which I don't have on my local as per your project requirement .... but surely I will setup that very soon
In the meantime could you please tell me are you doing integration testing or unit testing? and could you please provide your error log after mocking PropertyService

Comment: Thats okay. The error i got after mocking has been mentioned in the comments of the other answer.

Comment: Arpan I have updated the solution, please go through with that.

Comment: Thanks!The update solution worked as a charm!. There remains one doubt though-- I am still not able to access the prop service in my test class , your solution also hardcodes the value of the `authKey` . I tried getting it from the `PropertyService` but got an error--- I can live by hardcoding in the test class , so this **is not imp**, if u wish and have free time u can look into this issue....

Comment: `null
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /customer
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json", Content-Length:"151"]
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.spring.liquibase.demo.controller.HomeController
           Method = com.spring.liquibase.demo.controller.HomeController#addCustomer(CustomerDto)
Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null
`

Comment: `
ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 500
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Type:"text/plain;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"34"]
     Content type = text/plain;charset=UTF-8
             Body = Failed to add customer due to null
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []`.

Comment: And there is one more error. This is a major one-- my test case passes even if i give a **wrong** `authId` . Please try in your local and let me know if u r having the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

*And there is one more error. This is a major one-- my test case passes even if i give a wrong authId . Please try in your local and let me know if u r having the same behaviour.*

Off-course your test will be passed because your code is only checking the conditions it's not preventing the code to get executed, Please refer your code below:

```
try {
        if ((!customerDto.getAuthId().equals(propertyService.getKeytoAddCustomer()))) {
            System.out.println("If check failed: "+propertyService.getKeytoAddCustomer());
            System.out.println("Unauthorized access attempted");
            message = "Unauthorized access attempted";
            finalMessage = new ResponseEntity<>(message, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
        System.out.println("If check passed :"+propertyService.getKeytoAddCustomer());

        Customer customer = mapper.mapToEntity(customerDto);
        customerService.addCustomer(customer);
        message = "Customer with " + customer.getId() + " sucessfully added";
        finalMessage = new ResponseEntity<>(message, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

Over here under if condition you are only executing the block of codes and then instructed to execute the block of code which is outside the if condition.

So under if condition it's doing nothing. So you have to improve your code as per your expected behaviour.

If you would like to prevent your code execution then please refer the code below

```
try {
        if ((!customerDto.getAuthId().equals(propertyService.getKeytoAddCustomer()))) {
            System.out.println("If check failed: "+propertyService.getKeytoAddCustomer());
            System.out.println("Unauthorized access attempted");
            message = "Unauthorized access attempted";
            return new ResponseEntity<>(message, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
        System.out.println("If check passed :"+propertyService.getKeytoAddCustomer());

        Customer customer = mapper.mapToEntity(customerDto);
        customerService.addCustomer(customer);
        message = "Customer with " + customer.getId() + " sucessfully added";
        finalMessage = new ResponseEntity<>(message, HttpStatus.OK);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        message = "Failed to add customer due to " + e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
        finalMessage = new ResponseEntity<>(message, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

Here I have set the return statement under If condition.

But If you want to fail the current test case where you comparing the message then please refer the code below:

```
try {
        if ((!customerDto.getAuthId().equals(propertyService.getKeytoAddCustomer()))) {
            System.out.println("If check failed: "+propertyService.getKeytoAddCustomer());
            System.out.println("Unauthorized access attempted");
            message = "Unauthorized access attempted";
            finalMessage = new ResponseEntity<>(message, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }else {
            System.out.println("If check passed :" + propertyService.getKeytoAddCustomer());

            Customer customer = mapper.mapToEntity(customerDto);
            customerService.addCustomer(customer);
            message = "Customer with " + customer.getId() + " sucessfully added";
            finalMessage = new ResponseEntity<>(message, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        message = "Failed to add customer due to " + e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
        finalMessage = new ResponseEntity<>(message, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

Here you just need to set the block of code which is outside the if condition under the else part.

Comment: Yes , that was a silly mistake on my part, I forgot the return statement, but now , it has come back to point 0. Now after adding the return statement after if-check(ur `If you would like to prevent your code execution then please refer the code below`  example code). The test class always returns status `401` `uauthorized`. After debugging i noticed that `athKey` in `HomeController` is null--like before. Have u tried this in ur local? Looking forward to ur reply!

Comment: Hi...Did u get a chance to try this out?

Answer (score 0):

Try mocking the PropertyService with either `@MockBean` or `@Mock`.

I notice you're missing `@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)` above the class definition which you'll need for unit testing Mvc Controllers.
[Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39865596/difference-between-using-mockmvc-with-springboottest-and-using-webmvctest)

If `@MockBean` doesn't work.

Try:

Using `Mockito.when()`, you can simply return your desired/expected result and when the desired method is called.

Use `Mockito.verify()` to ensure the desire when is executed.

```
when(propertyService.getKeytoAddCustomer()).thenReturn("Desired String");

when(customerService.addCustomer(customerObject)).thenReturn("Desired result");

//DO mvc.perform(...);

verify(propertyService).getKeytoAddCustomer();

verify(customerService).addCustomer(customerObject());
```

**Problem Two**

The issue with the property file I assume is because you're using `spring.profile.active=dev` but property file is test/resources is `application.properties` instead of `application-dev.properties` despite that it is the only property file in test/resources. Rename the files exactly the same in both resources folder and see what happens.

Comment: Problem 2 solution did not work, still hardcoded the value, but after adding `@WebMvcTest(HomeController.class)` I am getting this error---`Description:

Field propertyService in com.spring.liquibase.demo.controller.HomeController required a bean of type 'com.spring.liquibase.demo.utility.PropertyService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.spring.liquibase.demo.utility.PropertyService' in your configuration.`

Comment: if i use @SpringBootTest above my test class then aslo same error, PropertyService is null.

Comment: Don't use `@SpringBootTest`. Use `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` instead.
Did you defined `@MockBean PropertyService propertyService;` like so?

Comment: I am using jUnit5 so `@RunWith` is replcaed with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` i am using this