# Why my org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc framework is failing to resolve constructor parameters of a controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin, junit, mockk

I want to create a unit tests for my Spring Boot app, but I receive following error during launching one of the `UserControllerTest` test:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.sample.order.OrderController required a bean of type 'com.sample.order.OrderRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.sample.order.OrderRepository' in your configuration.
```

When I'm trying to run tests from `UserControllerTest`, then `OrderController` fails to satisfy constructor parameters and vice versa.

The app is simple and has only two controllers, for managing orders and users. The source code has following structure:

```
src/
├── main
│   ├── kotlin
│   │   └── com
│   │       └── sample
│   │           ├── OrderApplication.kt
│   │           ├── order
│   │           │   ├── Order.kt
│   │           │   ├── OrderAssembler.kt
│   │           │   ├── OrderController.kt
│   │           │   └── OrderRepository.kt
│   │           └── user
│   │               ├── User.kt
│   │               ├── UserAssembler.kt
│   │               ├── UserController.kt
│   │               └── UserRepository.kt
│   └── resources
│       └── application.properties
└── test
    └── kotlin
        └── com
            └── sample
                ├── order
                │   └── OrderControllerTest.kt
                └── user
                    └── UserControllerTest.kt
```

In general for building my app I was trying to follow [the Spring Boot kotlin tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/).

The app itself runs without any problem. The problem lies when running tests.

I see that the action proposed by the framework is quite obvious:

> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.sample.order.OrderRepository' in your configuration.

, but why should I define a bean of type 'com.sample.order.OrderRepository' in configuration ? Shouldn't test be working out of the box when the app itself works and does not need any configuration?
Besides this the `OrderRepository` is type of interface:

```kotlin
interface OrderRepository: CrudRepository<Order, Long>
```

and I do not want to provide instantiation of this when Spring does its magic.

What I tried:

#### 1. Changing constructors of controllers to accept nullable parameters eg.:

From:

```kotlin
class OrderController(private val repository: OrderRepository
              ,private val assembler: OrderAssembler) {
...
```

To:

```kotlin
class OrderController(private val repository: OrderRepository? = null
              ,private val assembler: OrderAssembler? = null) {
...
```

It resolves the issue, but I do not want to have this solution from obvious reasons.

#### 2. Adding 'order' mocked variables to 'user' unit test

```kotlin
class UserControllerTest(@Autowired val mockMvc: MockMvc) {

    @MockkBean
    private lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    @SpykBean
    private lateinit var userAssembler: UserAssembler

    // !!!!!! NOTE: orderRepository inside user tests ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ 
    @MockkBean
    private lateinit var orderRepository: OrderRepository

    // !!!!!! NOTE: orderAssembler inside user tests ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ 
    @SpykBean
    private lateinit var orderAssembler: OrderAssembler
    

    @Test
    fun `Should form expected json response with user data`(){
        val user = User(id = 5, login="john.doe@aol.com", firstname = "John", lastname = "Doe")
        every { userRepository.findAll() } returns listOf(user)
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/users/").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk)
    }
}
```

It also resolves the issue, but it is ugly workaround.

#### 3. Setting explicit package name in ComponentScan

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.sample.order")
class OrderApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<OrderApplication>(*args)
}
```

This does not fix the issue.

The code of the UserController:

```kotlin
@RestController
class UserController(private val repository: UserRepository,
                     private val assembler: UserAssembler) {

    @GetMapping("/api/v1/user/{id}")
    fun findOne(@PathVariable id: Long): EntityModel<User> {
        val user = repository.findById(id)
        if (user.isPresent) {
            return assembler.toModel(user.get())
        }
        throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "This user does not exist")
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/v1/users")
    fun all(): CollectionModel<EntityModel<User>> {
        val users = repository.findAll().map {
            assembler.toModel(it)
        }
        return CollectionModel.of(users,  //
                linkTo<UserController>{all()}.withRel("all"))
    }
}
```

It does not help. Besides this my app can be run without any problem, so I think that component scanning is not a reason.

Versions used:

- Java: 14
- Kotlin: 1.4.0
- Spring Boot: 2.4.1
- springmockk: 1.1.3
- mockk:1.10.5

Below is full call stack:

```
Failed to resolve parameter [org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc mockMvc] in constructor [public com.sample.user.UserControllerTest(org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc)]
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Failed to resolve parameter [org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc mockMvc] in constructor [public com.sample.user.UserControllerTest(org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc)]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameter(ExecutableInvoker.java:221)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameters(ExecutableInvoker.java:174)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameters(ExecutableInvoker.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:61)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassTestDescriptor.java:342)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:289)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:281)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:269)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$3(ClassTestDescriptor.java:263)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$4(ClassTestDescriptor.java:262)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:82)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:133)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(SpringExtension.java:271)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.resolveParameter(SpringExtension.java:257)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameter(ExecutableInvoker.java:207)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'orderController' defined in file [.../webapp/build/classes/kotlin/main/com/sample/order/OrderController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.sample.order.OrderRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1206)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:923)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.sample.order.OrderRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1777)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 97 more
```

The tests source code:

1. OrderControllerTest.kt

```kotlin
package com.sample.order

import com.ninjasquad.springmockk.MockkBean
import com.ninjasquad.springmockk.SpykBean
import io.mockk.every
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status
import java.util.*

@WebMvcTest
class OrderControllerTest(@Autowired val mockMvc: MockMvc) {

    //Why we need that to have test compilable ?
    /*
    @MockkBean
    private lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    @SpykBean
    private lateinit var userAssembler: UserAssembler
    */

    @MockkBean
    private lateinit var orderRepository: OrderRepository

    @SpykBean
    private lateinit var orderAssembler: OrderAssembler

    @Test
    fun `Should form expected json response with order data`(){
        val order = Order(id = 7, date = 1501212321)
        every { orderRepository.findById(any()) } returns Optional.of(order)
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/order/7").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk)
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value(order.id))
    }
}
```

2. UserControllerTest.kt

```kotlin
package com.sample.user

import com.ninjasquad.springmockk.MockkBean
import com.ninjasquad.springmockk.SpykBean
import io.mockk.every
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status

@WebMvcTest
class UserControllerTest(@Autowired val mockMvc: MockMvc) {

    @MockkBean
    private lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    @SpykBean
    private lateinit var userAssembler: UserAssembler

    /*
    @MockkBean
    private lateinit var orderRepository: OrderRepository

    @SpykBean
    private lateinit var orderAssembler: OrderAssembler
    */

    @Test
    fun `Should form expected json response with user data`(){
        val user = User(id = 5, login = "john.doe@aol.com", firstname = "John", lastname = "Doe")
        every { userRepository.findAll() } returns listOf(user)
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/users").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk)
    }
}
```

The source code is available on [github](https://github.com/robcio83/spring-demo)

Comment: Can you share the complete code of your test? It looks like you may be using `@WebMvcTest` which will focus on your application's WebMVC beans, filtering out JPA repositories and the like.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @pollux552 yes I did. The solution in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to change the test annotations

- Add @AutoConfigureMockMvc
- Add @SpringBootTest
- Remove @WebMvcTest

Working test annotations look like this:

```kotlin
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
//@WebMvcTest
class UserControllerTest(@Autowired val mockMvc: MockMvc) {
    ...
```

`@AutoConfigureMockMvc` - enables and configures auto-configuration of MockMvc

`@SpringBootTest` - tells Spring Boot to go and look for a main configuration class (one with @SpringBootApplication for instance), and use that to start a Spring application context. SpringBootTest loads complete application and injects all the beans which can be slow.

`@WebMvcTest` - for testing the controller layer and you need to provide remaining dependencies required using Mock Objects.

More details can be found here:

- [other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39865596/difference-between-using-mockmvc-with-springboottest-and-using-webmvctest)
- [mkyong.com tutorial](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-test-unable-to-autowired-mockmvc/)